# Override UITabBarController Icon Selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I'm using a standard `UITabBarController` with icons at the bottom, each bringing to it's own`ViewController`. My question is basically:

Is there a way to override what happens when an icon is selected rather then directly bringing them to the view? Reason being is because I'm adding a login screen to pop up when the icon is selected, but would rather have the login screen appear right away if the user is not logged in rather then load the view first, then have it appear by using that views `viewWillAppear` method.

So basically instead of loading the view right away that it's intended too, if they're not logged in have another view 'modal-ly' appear instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UITabBarControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarControllerDelegate/tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:) has a delegate method 
`- tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:`, just implement it and check if user is logged in or not.

e.g.

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
  if (isLogin) {
    return YES;
  }
  else{
    //show your view controller here
    return NO;
  }
}
```

You can also check which view controller has been selected by comparing `viewController` parameter.